# PHP implode named array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a named array that look like this:

```
$arr = array('name'=>'somename','value'=>'somevalue');
```

I want to turn that array into something like this:

```
name='somename' value='somevalue'
```

I tried `http_build_query()` to do it.

```
echo http_build_query($arr, '', ' ');
```

But this is the result I get:

```
name=somename%21 value=somevalue%21
```

How can I get the result I want with `http_build_query()`? Or, is there any PHP function to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`http_build_query` returns a urlencoded string. If you don't want that you can run it through `urldecode`

```
$arr = array('name'=>"'somename'",'value'=>"'somevalue'");
print urldecode(http_build_query($arr,null,' '));
```

Comment: not return with single quote

Answer (score 0):

Try with `foreach()`

```
$arr = array('name'=>'somename','value'=>'somevalue');
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  $str.= "$k='$v' ";
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $result .= "$key='$value' ";
}
echo rtrim($result,' ');
```